# Finding type hierarchy assemblies using Mono.Cecil

Tags: c#, reflection, assemblies, mono.cecil

I am trying to implement a method that receives a type and returns all the assemblies that contain its base types.

For example:
Class *`A`* is a base type (class *`A`* belongs to assembly *c:\A.dll*)
Class *`B`* inherits from *`A`* (class *`B`* belongs to assembly *c:\B.dll*)
Class *`C`* inherits from *`B`* (class *`C`* belongs to assembly *c:\c.dll*)

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetAssembliesFromInheritance(string assembly, 
                                                        string type)
{
    // If the method recieves type C from assembly c:\C.dll
    // it should return { "c:\A.dll", "c:\B.dll", "c:\C.dll" }
}
```

My main problem is that `AssemblyDefinition` from Mono.Cecil does not contain any property like *Location*.

How can an assembly location be found given an *`AssemblyDefinition`*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An assembly can be composed of multiple modules, so it doesn't really have a location per se. The assembly's main module does have a location though:

```
AssemblyDefinition assembly = ...;
ModuleDefinition module = assembly.MainModule;
string fileName = module.FullyQualifiedName;
```

So you could write something along the line of:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetAssembliesFromInheritance (TypeDefinition type)
{
    while (type != null) {
        yield return type.Module.FullyQualifiedName;

        if (type.BaseType == null)
            yield break;

        type = type.BaseType.Resolve ();
    }
}
```

Or any other variant which pleases you more.

Comment: And from the author of Cecil, no less!